# Apache Spark: Reference pointer to the parent RDD

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I understand that SPARK maintains the lineage information for an RDD. Suppose I have an RDD "a" and using some transformation on that I produce a new RDD "b". In such a scenario, "a" is the parent RDD of "b". Is it possible to get back the RDD "a" from RDD "b" by referencing the parent pointer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what is the real question:

- yes - If you extend RDD for example. It is necessary for most of the implementations of `compute` method.
- no - dependencies are not publicly accessible so you cannot get parents from an instance of RDD.